# Applying Weights to Terms

Tags: game-theory

I am in a discussion with a friend and have a question regarding the use of weights.

He presented me with the equation below. It represents an individual's payoff for taking a particular action, say going shopping. The individual determines that going shopping has a value, $x$. Furthermore, the individual assigns a probability, $\theta$, that he will survive the drive to the store and receive $x$, and $\theta \in[0,1]$. There is also a cost associated with going shopping and in this case, the cost, $C$, is a function of effort, $e$. Additionally, $\lambda$ is a weight and is $\in [0,1]$ and $\lambda$ can be considered how much the individual is excited by, $x$. For example, if the person is very excited by $x$ then $\lambda=1$. Now, assume that someone wants to offer this individual a sum of money for not going shopping, this offer, $g$ would need to incorporate the above information and,

$$g=\frac{\lambda\theta x+C(e)(1-\lambda)}{\lambda}$$

Here are two perspectives regarding $\lambda$ in this expression:

**Perspective 1:** The mathematical use of $\lambda$ is appropriate since it's a weight and as such the method is to apply $\lambda$ to $\lambda\theta x+C(e)(1-\lambda)$ and then divide by $\lambda$.

**Perspective 2:** Yes, $\lambda$ is a weight, however since we are not seeking the weighted mean, dividing by $\lambda$ is not appropriate. The expression, $\lambda\theta x+C(e)(1-\lambda)$ is fine as is. Also, since $\lambda$ can $=0$, there is a circumstance under which there is no defined solution.

I have other issues with the equation, but my primary concern is how the weights were used.

Both he and I are rusty on our math and can use some help.

Comment: Since $x$ is a benefit and $C$ is cost, shouldn't we have a "$-$" between $\lambda \theta x$ and $C(e) (1-\lambda)$?

Comment: What happens if the individual does not survive? This sorry event has probability $1-\theta$ and should enter the determination of value.

Comment: @mlc I agree, there are other issues with equation. Right now, he and I are just hashing out $\lambda$. I can't understand a reason that one would ever assign a weight and then divide by the assigned weight.

Comment: If you want to take pondered mean of $\theta x$ and $C(e)$, dividing by $\lambda$ makes no sense. The mean of $u$ and $v$ is $\frac{\alpha u+\beta v}{\alpha+\beta}$, but here $\alpha+\beta=1$. To be more precise : what would be the effect of dividing by $\lambda$ if $\lambda$ approaches $0$ or $1$ ?

Comment: I believe the right tag for this discussion may be (economics).

Comment: I had it in economics, but was asked to move it to mathematics since the heart of the question is related to the operation of assigning a weight and then dividing by the same weight. My friend's response is: "this is just how you do weightings."

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS, It sounds like you are saying that his approach to weighting is unreasonable. That if he wanted the weighted mean (which he does not...he doesn't want a mean at all) he would apply weights to each term and then divide by the sum of all the weights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how an economist would look at the problem, based on your description. Going shopping yields a random reward, given by $\lambda x$ with probability $\theta$ and by death (or hospitalisation?) with probability $1 - \theta$. Assuming expected utility and risk neutrality, we have an expected benefit $\theta \lambda x + (1 - \theta) D$, where $D$ is the "benefit" of death. Moreover, there is a (certain) cost $C(e)$, to be subtracted from the expected benefit in order to know the value of the offer
$$g = \theta \lambda x + (1 - \theta) D - C(e)$$

You may want to ask your friend to micro-found his/her claim that "$\lambda$ can be considered how much the individual is excited by $x$". A simple utility function $u(x)$ seems to be a more natural approach.

Comment: I agree with your approach as it fits with reality.